# How do I eliminate this shadow from my product photography?

Tags: lighting, product-photography, shadows

I've been taking pictures of shoes inside the box shown in the picture, and the lighting is on the ceiling on the inside of the box. I'm also attaching a picture so you can see which shadows I want to eliminate, as doing it in Photoshop is not efficient time-wise, and not perfectly accurate. Keep in mind, that the box's sides can be unfolded.

The shadows are the ones on the outsole and in front of the heel.

I tried using two lamps that I have (Professional Quartz Light QL-500) but then I had shadows on the side and still didn't eliminate that particular one. I really don't know a lot about lighting, so maybe you guys could offer me light positioning advice and if I might be needing another lamp like those big umbrella-like ones?

Please forgive my lack of photographic lingo knowledge, I'm really new to photography!

Thank you in advance.

[image: The Box]
[image: The Product With Shadows]

Comment: Just a statement, I think almost all except the top answer are really just suggestions as written, they maybe should have been comments instead, although if the writers want to add some information/effort several could be valuable additions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More light (from more directions) might help.  I've got a light tent somewhat similar to yours, though its construction is translucent on all sides, allowing me to light it from the outside.

I've had decent luck illuminating the tent with speedlites on multiple sides, and in some cases, the bottom, too (I put the tent on a glass coffee table and placed a speedlite below).  The tent does even the light considerably, but as you can see in this picture, a small amount of shadow is still visible.  This is not one of the shots I lit from below, by the way.  That might very well have eliminated the remaining shadow, but in this case, I liked the small remaining gradation and shadow.

[image]

Comment: For a minute I thought the image was something you were suggesting he purchases and not just an example of good lighting lol.

Comment: Just a shot from a review...

Answer (score 3):

Use opaque white acrylic glas and light it with diffused light (softbox or so) from behind/beneath. Use a dull one to avoid reflections.

My example is with glossy/polished glass, not dull. That is because I did want the reflection (and because I did not have dull plate of that glass :-) ) 
http://fc-foto.de/27416430
Set:
http://fc-foto.de/27389485

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a perfect white background? Why not experiment with some form of stand that lifts the item being photographed off the white surface, allowing light to get underneath. You may have to add extra lights and of course position the stand and/or camera so the the stand is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of eliminating the shadows via lighting, why not try to suspend the shoe via two thin metal rods?  You then take a picture of a shoe that is in mid air and there won't be any shadows near the shoe.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look into light tables: LED or other even-lit surfaces. See [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=light%20table&safe=off&es_sm=119&biw=1276&bih=682&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=5QRCVciSLImcoQSWkYCIDw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=light%20table%20product%20photography) for pictures